# Логирование Tomcat

Tags: tomcat

Всем привет. Подскажите пожалуйста, как на Tomcat настроить логирование http-запросов (чтобы response/request сыпались в catalina.out или в какой-нибудь другой текстовый файл). Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 0):

Они логгируются в access файл

```
/{tomcat folder}/logs/localhost_access_log.yyyy-mm-dd.txt
```

Comment: Этот файл пуст. Логоривание сюда по умолчанию включено? Или надо руками включить?

Comment: да, по умолчанию там, а вы делали запросы?

Comment: Хм... я, мягко говоря, новичок в этом. А как сделать запрос?

Comment: вы задеплоили своё приложение? Оно открывается по ссылке? По-умолчанию localhost:8080

Comment: Да, приложение работает. Вы про запросы от приложения? (туплю, прошу прощения). Запросы идут. Но в файле за сегодя пусто, за прошедшие дни - запись вида: IP - - [18/Jun/2019:15:06:43 +0300] "POST /processing-middle/check-cost HTTP/1.1" 500 -

Comment: ну да, это оно, хм, странно что не показываются текщие

Comment: а за сегодня точно были запросы?

Comment: Да, за сегодня запросы были

Comment: может быть у вас другой хост контейнера? Там может быть файл с названием вашего хоста, т.е. не localhost, а какой-нибудь mydomainname

Comment: там есть catalina.date.log, catalina.out, host-manager.log, localhost.date.log, localhost_access_log.date.txt и manager.date.log

Comment: Ну тогда должно быть в access. Попробуйте обратиться к localhost:8080/manager/text и проверьте, есть ли запись

Comment: Хорошо, попробую. Спасибо.